# php switch for a null string

Tags: php, switch-statement

For the following php program with a switch statement, why '' give me $vSS=2 instead of =1?
Quite strange to me.  I am using PHP 5.5.9. 
I can add case '': to resolve the problem, but I am curious why PHP give $vSS=2 instead of 
$vSS=1. Is it normal or a bug?

```
<?php
  R(15); // 1 ok
  R(''); // why give me 2
  R(40); // 2 ok
  R(70); // 3 ok
#
  function R($SS){
    switch($SS){
      case $SS<=20: $vSS=1;break;
      case ($SS>20 and $SS<=49.9): $vSS=2;  // why here?
        if($SS == '') echo "DEBUG: SS is a null string.<br>\n";
        break;
      case ($SS<=100 and $SS>49.9): $vSS=3; break;
      default:$vSS=0 ;
    }
    echo "DEBUG:(SS/vSS) $SS:$vSS\n";
  }
?>

------ RESULT
DEBUG:(SS/vSS) 15:1
DEBUG: SS is a null string.<br>
DEBUG:(SS/vSS) :2
DEBUG:(SS/vSS) 40:2
DEBUG:(SS/vSS) 70:3
```

Comment: `function R()`? `echo "DEBUG:(SS/vSS) $SS:$vSS\n";` oh, I like it. @Barmar is right, `switch - case` doesn't work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barmar is right, expression in `case()` is compared to `switch(something_here)` but you don't have to cahnge your all your code to `if/elsif/elsif/.../...` logic. Just change `switch()` statement to `true`

```
switch(true) { // <-- this part only
  case $SS<=20:
      $vSS=1;
      break;
  case ($SS>20 and $SS<=49.9):
    $vSS=2;  // why here?
    // must not be here
    // if($SS == '') echo "DEBUG: SS is a null string.<br>\n";
    break;
  case ($SS<=100 and $SS>49.9):
      $vSS=3; 
      break;
  case $SS=='': // you can check it here
      echo "DEBUG: SS is a null string.<br>\n";
      break;
  default:
      $vSS=0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand how `switch` works. It compares the value in `switch($SS)` with each of the `case` values, it doesn't just test each `case`. So

```
switch ($SS) {
case $SS<=20:
```

is similar to:

```
if ($SS == ($SS<=20))
```

The reason the second case is being executed is because `($SS > 20 && $SS <= 49.9)` is false, and `false` is considered equal to zero or an empty string.

You shouldn't use `switch` for what you're doing, you should use `if/then/elseif/else`:

```
if ($SS <= 20) {
    $vSS = 1;
} elseif ($SS <= 49.9) {
    $vSS = 2;
} else {
    $vSS = 0;
}
```